# How can I make Synergy accommodate the dead space around dual monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, synergy

I have desktop with two monitors (monitors 1 and 2) and a laptop (monitor 3). I've placed the laptop below the desktop using Synergy's interactive configuration screen.

The resulting behavior is that one of the desktop's monitors connects to half of the laptop's screen:

[image: Current Synergy behavior]

but given the laptop's physical position, this arrangement would make more sense:

[image: Desired Synergy behavior]

How can I make it do that?

Answer (score 5):

I would try using ranges. (I'm estimating that the amount of left to right spread that is the right monitor is 60 percent. Starting at 40% from the left and extending to 100%.)

Notice the black space? That part counts. That's why I say to put it 40% in instead of 0% to 100%. Try this first one.

```
section: links
    Desktop:
        down(40,100) = Laptop
    Laptop:
        up = Desktop(40,100)
end
```

So far, this is the best that I think it can do. I tried to figure out a way you could move from Desktop-Monitor1 or monitor 2, but I just ended up only being able to leave the right side of monitor 2, not monitor one. Same problem trying to make it so that you can leave Lappy and move left onto D1 - you end up arriving on D2 [image: Diagram of monitor arrangement]

Answer (score -1):

If i understand the problem correctly it seems a possible solution would be to make `screen 2` the synergy Server ( and therefore screen 1). It seems like synergy intepretes the position in relation to the server.

EDIT: You can create or edit the synergy configuration file, which has several sections. In the section 'links' you can edit the relativ position of the screens to each other (as in edges). You can find a guide how to do this at http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/configuration.html 
If you replace host1 with the correct names it should something like that:

`section: links
   host1:
            down = host 2`

host2:
            up = host1

If host1 is your primary screen it should switch to it, and for your other monitor you dont need synergy anyway.

(Edited with my phone so sry for the formatting)

Comment: The Synergy server is already running on the computer that has monitor 2. I've updated my question to try to make this clearer.

Comment: Is #1 your primary screen? I would suggest try to switch it to #2 and see if it changes anything but i dont know anything specifoc what could help

Comment: I realize that this might have stemmed from misunderstanding, but changing which machine is hosting Synergy is not a solution to this problem.